# How to extract data from xml node in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

Below is my xml, which is recorded in a database table.

```
<root>
  <pagelocation>
    <nodeid>3178</nodeid>
      <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
        </webpart>
    </pagelocation>
    <pagelocation>
        <NodeId>3180</NodeId>
            <webpart id="editabletexttitle;a36d4858-5d61-49b6-a860-221ad0b72310">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
      </pagelocation>
</root>
```

I need to get only the information belonging to 
`<webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">` how to write a query for something like this in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this as follows:

- this XML (and many other XMLs) are living in a table's column in many rows
- Each of these XMLs have more or less `<webpart>` nodes
- Within one XML an `@id` is unique
- You want to read the text *within* this given `webpart` element

The following code will insert three rows into a declared table simulating three different cases.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Descritpion VARCHAR(100),XmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('Contains the Id'
,N'<root>
    <pagelocation>
        <NodeId>3180</NodeId>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">
                    Some Content 
            </webpart>
      </pagelocation>
</root>')
,('Does not contain the Id'
,N'<root>
  <pagelocation>
    <nodeid>3178</nodeid>
      <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
            Other Content 
        </webpart>
    </pagelocation>
</root>')
,('Multiple IDs, one of them fitting'
,N'<root>
  <pagelocation>
    <nodeid>3178</nodeid>
      <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
            id is not correct
        </webpart>
    </pagelocation>
    <pagelocation>
        <NodeId>3180</NodeId>
            <webpart id="editabletexttitle;a36d4858-5d61-49b6-a860-221ad0b72310">
                    Same here 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">
                    Yeah! that is is 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
                    One more 
            </webpart>
      </pagelocation>
</root>')
```

--The id you are searching for can be defined as parameter

```
DECLARE @SearchFor NVARCHAR(100)=N'editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d';
```

--This command uses `.query()` first to get hands on the right node, than `.value` to get the textual content

```
SELECT *
      ,XmlColumn.query('//webpart[@id=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]').value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Content
FROM @tbl;
```

--This command uses the `XQuery` in `.value()` directly (faster, stops at the first occurance)

```
SELECT *
      ,XmlColumn.value('(//webpart[@id=sql:variable("@SearchFor")])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Content
FROM @tbl
```

It is OK to use `CROSS APPLY .nodes()` (like in other answers), but - if you a) don't expect more than one row, or b) want to read different values from one location, it is kind of overhead...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo. your solution help to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right(your "only" is not clear), here is an example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<root>
  <pagelocation>
    <nodeid>3178</nodeid>
      <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
        </webpart>
    </pagelocation>
    <pagelocation>
        <nodeid>3180</nodeid>
            <webpart id="editabletexttitle;a36d4858-5d61-49b6-a860-221ad0b72310">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
      </pagelocation>
</root>'

SELECT n.c.value('@id', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM 
@xml.nodes('/root/pagelocation/webpart') AS n(c)
```

Output:

```
editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127
editabletexttitle;a36d4858-5d61-49b6-a860-221ad0b72310
editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d
editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses an XPath expression to look up the node(s) with the specific ID. This uses the `nodes()` function in SQL Server, `CROSS APPLY` to apply it to the XML in the table, and selects using the `value()` function.

If you are unclear on how this works: research XPath expressions, XPath/XQuery functionality in SQL Server and `CROSS APPLY`.

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE(x XML);
INSERT INTO @t(x)VALUES('<root>
  <pagelocation>
    <nodeid>3178</nodeid>
      <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
        </webpart>
    </pagelocation>
    <pagelocation>
        <NodeId>3180</NodeId>
            <webpart id="editabletexttitle;a36d4858-5d61-49b6-a860-221ad0b72310">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
            <webpart id="editabletextdescriptio2;b5518b76-9fe6-47d2-8d8b-4ab169d3a127">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non nisl lacus. Donec in rutrum lorem, consectetur semper nunc. 
            </webpart>
      </pagelocation>
</root>');

SELECT
    n.v.value('.','NVARCHAR(256)')
FROM
    @t AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.x.nodes('//webpart[@id="editabletextdescriptio1;f4873da3-bf3b-43d3-9dc6-cdabfa8c7b6d"]') AS n(v);
```